# What will be the Selenium WebDriver Script for direct drag file from local drive and Drop it to web app?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

Please help me to knowing the Selenium WebDriver script for direct Dragging a file from Local drive window to the Web App?

Comment: sendkeys isn't happening for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag & drop functionality of webdriver(In fact whole webdriver API) is only restricted to web applications & can't be used for desktop apps(Or with local driver window).So there will be no webdriver script for your situation.

You can use third party tools such as **[AUTO IT](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/beta/autoit/docs/)** or **[Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/)** to accomplish such tasks.

Comment: Thank u Shoaib,, I will try to use it.

Comment: You're welcome !! what about marking my answer as final one :-D